# Very slow scrolling in JScrollPane when using per-pixel transparency

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jscrollpane

I am using per-pixel transparency using `AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque()` on `JFrame`, that contains `JScrollPane`. When transparency is on, the scrolling in that pane is very slow and laggy, without it is not. Trying this on Windows 7 and JDK 6.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    super();

    setUndecorated(true);
    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false); //this turns JScrollPane inside of this JFrame slow and laggy
}
```

Have anyone issued this? Thanks!

Comment: for potential answerers could be important Java version and native os too, for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Please follow the [sscce](http://sscce.org/) guidelines. Following this standard makes it easier for others to help you answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any scrolling issue, nor to create testing scenario for code that is based on good Swing rules, this code is quite too hard for processor(s) and GPU, Java6, Win7 64b

[image][image][image][image]

from code

```
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class ViewPortFlickeringOriginal {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table");
    private JViewport viewport = new JViewport();
    private Rectangle RECT = new Rectangle();
    private Rectangle RECT1 = new Rectangle();
    private JTable table = new JTable(50, 3);
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private int count = 0;
    private GradientViewPortOriginal tableViewPort;
    private static boolean loggerOpacity;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private static JButton button;

    public ViewPortFlickeringOriginal() {
        tableViewPort = new GradientViewPortOriginal(table);
        viewport = tableViewPort.getViewport();
        viewport.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                if (tableViewPort.bolStart) {
                    RECT = table.getCellRect(0, 0, true);
                    RECT1 = table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true);
                    Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();
                    if (viewRect.intersects(RECT)) {
                        System.out.println("Visible RECT -> " + RECT);
                        tableViewPort.paintBackGround(new Color(250, 150, 150));
                    } else if (viewRect.intersects(RECT1)) {
                        System.out.println("Visible RECT1 -> " + RECT1);
                        tableViewPort.paintBackGround(new Color(150, 250, 150));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Visible RECT1 -> ???? ");
                        tableViewPort.paintBackGround(new Color(150, 150, 250));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(tableViewPort);
        button = new JButton("Change Opacity for Java6 / Win7");
        button.setBounds(100, 100, 50, 50);
        button.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(button);
        loggerOpacity = true;
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Object src = evt.getSource();
                if (src == button && loggerOpacity) {
                    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(frame, 0.80f);
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(50, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(new RepaintManager() {

            @Override
            public void addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
                Container con = c.getParent();
                while (con instanceof JComponent) {
                    if (!con.isVisible()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (con instanceof GradientViewPortOriginal) {
                        c = (JComponent) con;
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        w = con.getWidth();
                        h = con.getHeight();
                    }
                    con = con.getParent();
                }
                super.addDirtyRegion(c, x, y, w, h);
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(100, updateCol());
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.out.println("updating row " + (count + 1));
                TableModel model = table.getModel();
                int cols = model.getColumnCount();
                int row = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    row = count;
                    table.changeSelection(row, 0, false, false);
                    timer.setDelay(100);
                    Object value = "row " + (count + 1) + " item " + (j + 1);
                    model.setValueAt(value, count, j);
                }
                count++;
                if (count >= table.getRowCount()) {
                    timer.stop();
                    table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
                    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            table.clearSelection();
                            tableViewPort.bolStart = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ViewPortFlickeringOriginal viewPortFlickering = new ViewPortFlickeringOriginal();
            }
        });
    }
}

class GradientViewPortOriginal extends JScrollPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int h = 50;
    private BufferedImage img = null;
    private BufferedImage shadow = new BufferedImage(1, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private JViewport viewPort;
    public boolean bolStart = false;

    public GradientViewPortOriginal(JComponent com) {
        super(com);
        viewPort = this.getViewport();
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BLIT_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
        paintBackGround(new Color(250, 150, 150));
    }

    public void paintBackGround(Color g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = shadow.createGraphics();
        g2.setPaint(g);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstIn);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0f), 0, h,
                new Color(0.1f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.5f)));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (img == null || img.getWidth() != getWidth() || img.getHeight() != getHeight()) {
            img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        super.paint(g2);
        Rectangle bounds = getViewport().getVisibleRect();
        g2.scale(bounds.getWidth(), -1);
        int y = (getColumnHeader() == null) ? 0 : getColumnHeader().getHeight();
        g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, -bounds.y - y - h, null);
        g2.scale(1, -1);
        g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, bounds.y + bounds.height - h + y, null);
        g2.dispose();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

but I'm able to demonstrating lazy scrolling for JScrollPane contains others JComponents as is JTable or JList or JTextArea or JTextPane

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListPanel extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ListPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement(createButtons("one"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("two"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("three"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("four"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("five"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("six"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("seven"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("eight"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("nine"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("ten"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("eleven"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("twelwe"));
        JList list = new JList(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(new PanelRenderer());
        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(list);
        final JScrollBar scrollBar = scroll1.getVerticalScrollBar();
        scrollBar.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("JScrollBar's current value = " + scrollBar.getValue());
            }
        });
        add(scroll1);
        JScrollPane scroll2 = new JScrollPane(createPanel());
        add(scroll2);        
        final JScrollBar scrollBar1 = scroll2.getVerticalScrollBar();
        scrollBar1.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("JScrollBar's current value = " + scrollBar1.getValue());
            }
        });

    }

    public static JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 1, 1));
        panel.add(createButtons("one"));
        panel.add(createButtons("two"));
        panel.add(createButtons("three"));
        panel.add(createButtons("four"));
        panel.add(createButtons("five"));
        panel.add(createButtons("six"));
        panel.add(createButtons("seven"));
        panel.add(createButtons("eight"));
        panel.add(createButtons("nine"));
        panel.add(createButtons("ten"));
        panel.add(createButtons("eleven"));
        panel.add(createButtons("twelwe"));
        return panel;
    }

    public static JButton createButtons(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListPanel frame = new ListPanel();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(270, 200);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class PanelRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JButton renderer = (JButton) value;
            renderer.setBackground(isSelected ? Color.red : list.getBackground());
            return renderer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, setting proper scroll mode for viewport on my JScrollPane did the job! Thank you very much! Very helpfull.